# How to connect to django-admin-honeypot listener

Tags: django

The [docs](http://django-admin-honeypot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/usage.html#the-honeypot-signal) say

> Every time a login attempt occurs, the
>   admin_honeypot.signals.honeypot() signal is fired off. You can setup
>   listeners to this in order to send out any custom notifications or
>   logging.

How do I connect my logger to this?

My code:
settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
     'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format'   : '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class'    : 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
         'sysadm_file': {
            'level'    : 'DEBUG',
            'class'    : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename' : 'xlogger/sysadm.log',
            'maxBytes' : LOGFILE_SIZE,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    'loggers': {
        'sysadm.views': {
           'handlers' : ['sysadm_file',],
           'level'    : 'DEBUG',
           'propagate': True,
        }
    },
}
```

Signals.py

```
import logging  
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
from admin_honeypot.signals import honeypot  

@receiver(honeypot)  
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    logger.warning('hello world')
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [listening to signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals)?

Comment: Yes. But sadly I still don't get it. I have been able to create loggers for my views but I can't seem to catch the honeypot signal

Comment: In that case post the code that you currently have so that we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code is correct. I mistakenly placed it in signals instead of views.